# Can't find a Hadith regarding always being ready to mount an animal

Tags: hadith, clothing, animals, jihad

I remember that I read 2 months ago a Hadith. It stated approx. that we have to wear garments which let us always be ready to mount an animal. I can't find it anymore, I don't know where I read it and what grade it is.